# Feynman Lectures: Resonance - Problem with Formula

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resonance

I am reading Volume 1 Chapter 23 of FLP, and I have come across something rather strange. Feynman says that:

$$
\rho^2 =\frac{1}{m^2[(\omega^2-\omega_0^2)^2+\gamma^2\omega^2]}
$$

A graph of this can be seen here ([source](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/img/FLP_I/f23-02/f23-02_tc_big.svgz)).

[image]

If I let $\omega_0^2 = 1$, $\gamma^2 = 1$, and $m^2 = 1$ then I get:

$$
\rho^2 =\frac{1}{(\omega^2-1)^2+\omega^2}
$$

According to Feynman's graph, the maximum should have $\omega$-coordinate $\omega_0^2$. However this is clearly not correct. If one finds the minima of $(\omega^2-1)^2+\omega^2$, they occur at $\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, hence the maxima of $\rho^2$ will not occur when $\omega^2_0 = \omega$.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I added the diagram I believe you are referring to - the original link seems to be inaccessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot see the image for some reason, but I think $\gamma$ is rather small there. The term $\gamma^2\omega^2$ shifts the maximum position, as a matter of fact. You took a rather strong "friction" ($\gamma=1$), which makes the resonance "frequency" smaller (longer period T). It is physically comprehensible.

Comment: Right. At high damping, there is a shift in the resonance. The plot that Feynman drew was for a high Q system, where the resonance does not shift perceptibly.

Comment: Yes - often referred to as the "damped natural frequency". If one plots the roots of the denominator equation in the complex plane, the projection onto the real axis is the damped natural frequency.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in any graph maker (Ex. Microsoft Mathematics) that when You change $\gamma$
then $\rho^2$ maximum shifts a little bit and the center of maximum is getting closer $ \omega_0$ as $\gamma$ is getting closer to zero (no friction).